# Can we show alert box of javascript using Javascript Result in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am working on mvc4 web application. i developed Custom Action filter for check user permissions on Controller action method. i want to show alert box of jquery in custom filter can we show alert box in Custom Filter using JavaScript Result please guide me.

Comment: from filter attributes, you can raise `HttpException` which you can redirect to the client side and detect in jQuery's error to the alert

Comment: @ManishMishra brother I know this way but i want to know is this possible to show jquery or javascript alerbox in custom filter using JavaScriptResult class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *developed Custom Action filter for check user permissions on Controller action method*, create `TempData` in base controller, create instance of controller in Action filter, give your custom message to TempData about permission. And in `_Layout`, show message, after every page reloading:

To show TempData is like this:

```
@{
    var message = TempData["AlertMessage"] ?? string.Empty;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '@message';
    if(message) alert(message);
</script>
```

Comment: Bay can you please give me any code example?

Comment: can you share your action filter? If not, can you get controller instance there?

Comment: yes i get controller instance in action filter.

Comment: So, check 2 variants: 
1. Define Base Controller, and inside it define AlertMessage property in string type, and in filter, set value to it. Use AlertMessage.

2. Use TempData["AlertMessage"] in your action filter to set message.

Comment: message always will be same not different message will be you are not authroize to view this?

Comment: If there is not any Alert message set null it.  TempData["AlertMessage"] = null;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48259/discussion-between-ammar-and-jhoon-bey)